# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a ListBox in my webpage (I'm using ASP.NET Web Form 4) and when i want to Convert these ListBox' Items to String Array it's not working,
i use this code :

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] a= ListBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray();
}
```

when I click on `btnSend` and inspect it via Chrome Dev Tools (in the Console tab), I get an error like this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.String'

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ListBox.Items` collection contain [ListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx).

```
var texts = ListBox1.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Select(item => item.Text)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
ListBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```